# Encountering "Security Header Not Valid" white doing recurring payments using paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal sandbox to create the recurring payments. I have create one account in developer site and created the test accounts. For the sandbox account i copied the API credentials generated by the PAYPAL.

I copied the API credentials and placed in the properties file and executed the code using java.

When i execute the code i am getting "Security Header Not Valid" message. Below are the account details and the endpoints i am using.

```
acct1.UserName = {API User Name generated by paypal}
acct1.Password = {API Password generated by paypal}
acct1.Signature = {API Signature generated by paypal}
acct1.AppId=APP-80W284485P519543T

acct2.UserName = sdk-three_api1.sdk.com
acct2.Password = QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q
acct2.Signature = A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU
acct2.AppId = APP-80W284485P519543T

acct3.UserName = certuser_biz_api1.paypal.com
acct3.Password = D6JNKKULHN3G5B8A
acct3.CertKey = password
acct3.CertPath = resource/sdk-cert.p12
acct3.AppId=APP-80W284485P519543T

service.EndPoint.PayPalAPI = https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
service.EndPoint.PayPalAPIAA = https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0
service.EndPoint.Permissions = https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/
service.IPNEndpoint=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Please let me know if anything is missing in this. I have read paypal documentation and read other sites also but no use. I have stuck here from past 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

10002 'Security header' errors are pretty much always caused by incorrect credentials being passed to the API endpoint.
I would recommend you take a look at the previous answers for this error and review the suggestions made in them: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=paypal+10002